# enable the go to next step button, tried setting up state and created new onclick method in the radio button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

**update 2:**

hi,

- sorry I forgot to mention about the api call in my question earlier
- I making an api call in redux way.
- so in my actions/index.js file I am calling my api in getSports method.
- but the problem is when I try to retrieve the values I am getting an error.
  `A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See b.me/react-crossorigin-error for more information.`
- so I debugged the props in the class AsyncValidationForm `console.log("AsyncValidationForm  this.props---->", this.props);`
- there I dont see the getSports method.
- can You tell me how to retrieve the values so that I can assign the them to my radio button label.

https://codesandbox.io/s/yv1zpj874x

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export function testData() {
  let response = { data: "test" };
  return {

  };
}

export function getSports() {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users") //works
      .then(response => {

      })
      .catch(error => {

      });
  };
}
```

**AsyncValidationForm.js**

```
import * as actions from "../actions";


class AsyncValidationForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("AsyncValidationForm  this.props---->", this.props);

    this.state = {
      //pass down VerticalLinearStepper.js state if any
      username: this.props.username ? this.props.username : "",
      password: this.props.password ? this.props.password : "",
      //this determines whether any fields is filled or not from VerticalLinearStepper
      pristine:
        this.props.username || this.props.password || !this.props.disabledNext
          ? false
          : true
    };
  }
```

**radio button label in  AsyncValidationForm.js**

```
  <label>
          <Field
            name="sex"
            component={renderField}
            type="radio"
            value="male"
            checked={!this.props.disabledNext}
            onChange={this.passRadioValue}
          />{" "}
          Male
        </label>
```

- I am new to redux form.
- I am trying to enable the button after I click the radio button.
- to enable the go to next step button I tried setting up state and created new onclick method in the radio button.
- but still its throwing an error,
- not sure how to pass the radio button values to enable the button.
- Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.
- Providing my sandbox and relevant code snippet below.

**update1: now only this error has been removed** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/4jpkk394x7?moduleview=1

https://codesandbox.io/s/pjj6m1l9pq

**AsyncValidationForm.js**

```
const AsyncValidationForm = props => {
  console.log("AsyncValidationForm ---->");
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  // this.state = {

  //   disabled: false
  // };
  // this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled });
  const passRadioValue = (e) =>{
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="username"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Username"
      />
      <Field
        name="password"
        type="password"
        component={renderField}
        label="Password"
      />
      <label>
        <Field name="sex" 
        component={renderField} type="radio" value="male"
          onClick={this.passRadioValue("right")} />{" "}
        Male
      </label>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

**StepTemplate.js**

```
<Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={onNext}
          className={classes.button}
        >
          {canGoBack ? "Next" : "go to next step"}
        </Button>
```

Comment: Your sandbox should be a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. If the above snippets are the relevant code, then there should be almost nothing else in your sandbox.

Comment: @RyanCogswell hey I removed the unnecessaryu files, can you help me now

Comment: The sandbox looks no different to me.

Comment: Hey I am using stepper and reduce form so those codes should be there....not sure how to reproduce by removing this codes.... can you let me know

Comment: @RyanCogswell I tried in my sandbox, its not working...can you update in my sandbox

Comment: @nossr I think the answer is not locked anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/6zrw7r66rr

I have forked your codesandbox, and edit 4 files. Pretty sure it satisfies all your requirements stated above

VerticalLinearStepper.js: this is where we store our `username, password, disabledNext (radioButton)` state and `handleChange` method for `setState`. Then, we passed down the state to -> `Step1.js` -> `AsyncValidationForm.js`.

```
class VerticalLinearStepper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeStep: 0,
    //we set our state in this parent
    disabledNext: true,
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  steps = {
    "Select campaign settings": Step1,
    "Create an ad group": Step2,
    "Create an ad": Step3
  };

  //setState for disabledNext
  handleChangeDisabledNext = value => {
    this.setState({ disabledNext: value });
  };
  //setState for username, password
  handleChange = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  stepsCount = () => Object.values(this.steps).length;

  canGoBack = () => this.state.activeStep > 0;
  canGoForward = () => this.state.activeStep < this.stepsCount();

  isFinished = () => this.state.activeStep === this.stepsCount();

  handleBack = () => {
    if (this.canGoBack()) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ activeStep: prevState.activeStep - 1 }));
    }
  };

  handleNext = () => {
    if (this.canGoForward()) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1 }));
    }
  };

  handleReset = () => this.setState({ activeStep: 0 });

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { activeStep } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
          {Object.entries(this.steps).map(([label, CustomStep]) => (
            <Step key={label}>
              <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <CustomStep
                  canGoBack={this.canGoBack()}
                  canGoForward={this.canGoForward()}
                  onBack={this.handleBack}
                  onNext={this.handleNext}
                  classes={classes}
                  //we pass down the state and its' setState method
                  handleChangeDisabledNext={this.handleChangeDisabledNext}
                  disabledNext={this.state.disabledNext}
                  handleChange={this.handleChange}
                  username={this.state.username}
                  password={this.state.password}
                />
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
          ))}
        </Stepper>

        {this.isFinished() && (
          <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
            <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
            <Button onClick={this.handleReset} className={classes.button}>
              Reset
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In `AsyncValidationForm.js`, we bind `onChange` method to track the value and call the `setState` method and `this.props.handleChange` for `setState` in `VerticalLinearStepper.js`

```
const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  //checked is for radio, initialValue is for setting the username, password value
  checked,
  initialValue,
  meta: { asyncValidating, touched, error }
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <div className={asyncValidating ? "async-validating" : ""}>
        <input
          {...input}
          value={initialValue} //add value attr
          checked={checked} //add checked attr
          type={type}
          placeholder={label}
        />
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

class AsyncValidationForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("AsyncValidationForm ---->");

    this.state = {
      //pass down VerticalLinearStepper.js state if any
      username: this.props.username ? this.props.username : "",
      password: this.props.password ? this.props.password : "",
      //this determines whether any fields is filled or not from VerticalLinearStepper
      pristine:
        this.props.username || this.props.password || !this.props.disabledNext
          ? false
          : true
    };
  }

  passRadioValue = e => {
    this.setState({ pristine: false }, () => {
      this.props.handleChangeDisabledNext(!e.target.checked);
    });
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        [name]: value,
        pristine: false
      },
      () => {
        this.props.handleChange(name, value); //setState username, password of VerticalLinearStepper.js
      }
    );
  };

  resetForm = () => {
    this.props.handleChangeDisabledNext(true); //setState disabledNext of VerticalLinearStepper.js
    this.setState(
      {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        pristine: true
      },
      () => {
        this.props.handleChange("username", "");
        this.props.handleChange("password", "");
      }
    );

    this.props.reset();
  };

  // this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled });

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="username"
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Username"
          initialValue={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.handleChange("username")}
        />
        <Field
          name="password"
          type="password"
          component={renderField}
          label="Password"
          initialValue={this.state.password}
          onChange={this.handleChange("password")}
        />

        <label>
          <Field
            name="sex"
            component={renderField}
            type="radio"
            value="male"
            checked={!this.props.disabledNext}
            onChange={this.passRadioValue}
          />{" "}
          Male
        </label>

        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
            Sign Up
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            disabled={(pristine || submitting) && this.state.pristine} //add state.pristine checking
            onClick={this.resetForm}
          >
            Clear Values
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, in `StepTemplate.js` Add `disabledNext, checkDisabledNext` props. `checkDisabledNext` to determine whether the Next Button will have conditional checking or not. `disabledNext` is the disabled value.

```
const StepTemplate = ({
  classes,
  canGoBack,
  canGoForward,
  onBack,
  onNext,
  text,
  children,
  //we pass down these 2 values
  disabledNext,
  checkDisabledNext
}) => (
  <Fragment>
    <Typography>{text}</Typography>

    <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
      <div>
        {children}

        <Button
          disabled={!canGoBack}
          onClick={onBack}
          className={classes.button}
        >
          Back
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={onNext}
          className={classes.button}
          //determine whether we should check button disabled or not
          disabled={checkDisabledNext ? disabledNext : false}
        >
          {canGoBack ? "Next" : "go to next step"}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
);
```

This is `Step1.js`, here we just pass props to `StepTemplate` and `AsyncValidationForm`:

```
const Step = props => (
  <StepTemplate
    text={`
        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.
    `}
    //we want to apply checking on Step1.js, so we add checkDisabledNext attribute
    checkDisabledNext={true}
    // disabledNext={this.props.disabledNext} //no need to do this because will be passed with  {...props} below
    {...props}
  >
    <form>
      form for the first step here
      <div>test here</div>
      <AsyncValidationForm
        onSubmit={values => {
          console.log(values);
          alert(
            `Values: username: ${values.username} password: ${values.password}`
          );
        }}
        //these are the props passed down from VerticalLinearStepper.js
        handleChangeDisabledNext={props.handleChangeDisabledNext}
        disabledNext={props.disabledNext}
        handleChange={props.handleChange}
        username={props.username}
        password={props.password}
      />
    </form>
  </StepTemplate>
);
```

Here is the re-render issue fix:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vqvxj7ky4y
Update `VerticalLinearStepper.js`, then we dont need Step1.js file anymore, since we write the content of Step1.js in this file:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Stepper from "@material-ui/core/Stepper";
import Step from "@material-ui/core/Step";
import StepLabel from "@material-ui/core/StepLabel";
import StepContent from "@material-ui/core/StepContent";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

// import Step1 from "./steps/Step1";
import Step2 from "./steps/Step2";
import Step3 from "./steps/Step3";

import StepTemplate from "./steps/StepTemplate";
import AsyncValidationForm from "./forms/AsyncValidationForm";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "90%"
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  actionsContainer: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  },
  resetContainer: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  }
});

class VerticalLinearStepper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeStep: 0,
    //we set our state in this parent
    disabledNext: true,
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  steps = {
    //we pass the content of Step1 here, so we dont have to pass props
    "Select campaign settings": props => (
      <StepTemplate
        text={`
        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.

        For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much you're
        willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks and
        geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.
    `}
        //we want to apply checking on Step1.js, so we add checkDisabledNext attribute
        checkDisabledNext={true}
        disabledNext={this.state.disabledNext} //use this class' state
        {...props}
      >
        <form>
          form for the first step here
          <div>test here</div>
          <AsyncValidationForm
            onSubmit={values => {
              console.log(values);
              alert(
                `Values: username: ${values.username} password: ${
                  values.password
                }`
              );
            }}
            //we use this class setstate , no need to pass down props
            handleChangeDisabledNext={this.handleChangeDisabledNext}
            disabledNext={this.state.disabledNext}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            username={this.state.username}
            password={this.state.password}
          />
        </form>
      </StepTemplate>
    ),
    "Create an ad group": Step2,
    "Create an ad": Step3
  };

  //setState for disabledNext
  handleChangeDisabledNext = value => {
    this.setState({ disabledNext: value });
  };
  //setState for username, password
  handleChange = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  stepsCount = () => Object.values(this.steps).length;

  canGoBack = () => this.state.activeStep > 0;
  canGoForward = () => this.state.activeStep < this.stepsCount();

  isFinished = () => this.state.activeStep === this.stepsCount();

  handleBack = () => {
    if (this.canGoBack()) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ activeStep: prevState.activeStep - 1 }));
    }
  };

  handleNext = () => {
    if (this.canGoForward()) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1 }));
    }
  };

  handleReset = () => this.setState({ activeStep: 0 });

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { activeStep } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
          {Object.entries(this.steps).map(([label, CustomStep]) => (
            <Step key={label}>
              <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
              <StepContent>
                <CustomStep
                  canGoBack={this.canGoBack()}
                  canGoForward={this.canGoForward()}
                  onBack={this.handleBack}
                  onNext={this.handleNext}
                  classes={classes}
                />
              </StepContent>
            </Step>
          ))}
        </Stepper>

        {this.isFinished() && (
          <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
            <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
            <Button onClick={this.handleReset} className={classes.button}>
              Reset
            </Button>
          </Paper>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

VerticalLinearStepper.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object
};

export default withStyles(styles)(VerticalLinearStepper);
```

Additional reference: [React: Class Component vs Functional Component](https://itnext.io/react-component-class-vs-stateless-component-e3797c7d23ab)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187536/discussion-on-answer-by-alvin-theodora-enable-the-go-to-next-step-button-tried).

Comment: @Alvin for to retain the textbox value your using  `username: "",` but how your retaining the radio button values

Comment: @nossr Let's not adding comments anymore, we can use the chat

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code to enable a button on radio button click
If you want a more descriptive one please elaborate your question

```html
<html>
<script>
function enableButton()
{
 document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
}
</script>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onclick="JaaScript:enableButton()"> Male<br>
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey in AsyncValidationForm.js I have added the radio button can you add a click events there....so that it will help me to proceed further.... can you update in my sandbox directly

Comment: I tried in my sandbox, its not working...can you update in my sandbox

Answer (score 0):

First thing you will need to do is remove the reference to `this` from your *functional component*...

`onClick={this.passRadioValue("right")}`

TO

`onClick={passRadioValue("right")}`

Functional components inherit their functional context from the parent function's scope and don't have a `this` object. this will remove the immediate errors

Here's is a forked version or your codepen I've started for reference...

https://codesandbox.io/s/4jpkk394x7?moduleview=1

And some background on Functional (stateless) vs Class (stateful) components...

https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/

Comment: hey but the go to next step button should enable only after I select option in the radio button, can you help me with that

Comment: Yup, that was my next question for you. I’ll have to help you tomorrow though. Sorry, logging off for the night

Comment: Ok thanks... when you update can you update with the comments

Comment: Hey got busy? Can you please help

Comment: I'll have to get back to later tonight on this, but will definitely take a stab at it for then.

Comment: hi, any luck. It would be great if you let me know asap

Comment: can you help me with the redux problem too