# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I am trying to learn the map method. If I use this syntax `response.data.map(d =>` I am able to iterate data array and see the results, but if I use this syntax `response.data.map(([label, CustomStep]) => {`, I am getting the error below:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
```

**Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself?**

Providing my code snippet below:

```or-tag-here
axios
.get('http://world/sports/values')
.then(response => {
    console.log("sports--->", response.data.map(d => d.customFieldValueName));
    //this.setState({ playerRanks: response.data.map(d => d.customFieldValueName) });
    // es6 map
    //Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
    this.setState({
        playerRanks: response.data.map(([label, CustomStep]) => {
            label.customFieldValueName
        })
    })
})
```

**update 1:**

hey, I saw in console, data is an array inside that there are so many objects

```or-tag-here
 data: Array(19)
        [
            {
                "customFieldValueCode": "player1",
                "customFieldValueName": "player1",
                "isActive": "Y"
            },
            {
                "customFieldValueCode": "player 2",
                "customFieldValueName": "player 2",
                "isActive": "Y"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data you are expecting to receive? You can only use `[]` to destructure an array or an iterable; you would use `{}` to destructure an object.

Comment: You should checkout the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify( response.data,undefined,2))` The error is similar as `const [a,b]=22`

Comment: @HMR hey can you tell why your using undefined and 2 in your console and I am able to see the value in the console for this line `console.log(JSON.stringify( response.data,undefined,2))`

Comment: @HMR I didnt undertsand this line too ` const [a,b]=22`, I am getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: 22 is not iterable`

Comment: What @HMR and I were doing with this format of `console.log()` in general making the full (or rather desired) depth of the Object you're logging visible. Using a modern browser console.log(someObj) because it will allow you to inspect the entirety of the Object in the 'dev tools' console, but in a server-side environment `console.log()` will only give you `[Object]` and using `JSON.stringify(obj)`, which converts the object to a string, will still only show you the 'fist' level of that Object....

Comment: @cantuket hey when I use 2, it should max out at 2 right but why your telling it will maxout at 10

Comment: @cantuket hey can you explain this line in more detail `depth of first 2 layers of the Object`

Comment: @cantuket hey still confused, in my question i have given output...can you give your commemnts like saying which level 2 and level 5 it will help us to understand :(

Comment: @cantuket hey thanks, can yo help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239701/enable-the-go-to-next-step-button-tried-setting-up-state-and-created-new-onclic

Comment: @cantuket I use JSON.stringify because even in a browser when you expand a logged object it shows the object as it is now; not as it was at the time of logging (you may have mutated the object to fit or break the code close to the log) For example: `const arr = [{name:'Ben'}];console.log(arr);arr[0].name='Jerry';` when you expand the logged object it shows name is Jerry but that wasn't the name at the time of logging. The 2 in `JSON.stringify(obj,undefined,2)` is the amount of spaces used for the tab size of the formatted JSON.

Comment: @HMR Wow, whenever I concocted this crazy nesting conspiracy theory I must have managed to make my shoddy experiments conform to my theory somehow; `JSON.stringify()` clearly logs the full depth, always. To be honest I've been using the [Chrome's Node debugger](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/6792) for the past few years, so I haven't actually used `JSON.stringify()` for logging purpose in years.

Comment: @HMR wait .... what the ... I've been testing this with every data type and is this right...  Objects, and no other data types are, in the browser dev tools (not Node), unable to be defined until the end of execution, by `console.log()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Based off the data structure provided you could modify your code to...

```
axios
.get('http://world/sports/values')
.then(response => {
    this.setState({
        playerRanks: response.data.map(obj => {
            return obj.customFieldValueName
        })
    })
})
```

OR

```
    ...
    response.data.map(({customFieldValueName}) => {
        return customFieldValueName;
    })
    ...
```

OR even...

```
    ...
    response.data.map(({customFieldValueName}) => customFieldValueName)
    ...
```

But this would be my recommended solution to provide type checking on you data and proper error handling...

```
axios
.get('http://world/sports/values')
.catch(err=> console.log(err))
.then(({data}) => {                       // Axios always returns an Object, so I can safely 'attempt' to destructure 'data' property 
    if (data && data.length) {            // making sure 'data' does exist, it is an Array and has > 0 elements
      this.setState({
        playerRanks: data.map(obj => {    // Not destructuring here in case obj isn't actually an Object
            if (obj && obj.customFieldValueName) return customFieldValueName;
            return null;
        }).filter(elem=> elem)            // BIG-O notation: This sequence is O(2N), as in iterates over the entire Array first with .map(), then iterates over the entire Array again with .filter() to clear out 'null' values
      })
    }
})
```

In order to prevent your returned Array above from having a bunch of `null` elements when they don't conform to our assertions, you can use an `Array.reduce()` method to 'filter' out any `null`s...

```
axios
.get('http://world/sports/values')
.catch(err=> console.log(err))
.then(({data}) => {                       // Axios always returns an Object, so I can safely 'attempt' to destructure 'data' property 
    if (data && data.length) {            // making sure 'data' does exist, it is an Array and has > 0 elements
      this.setState({
        playerRanks: data.reduce((acc,obj) => {    // Not destructuring here in case obj isn't actually an Object
            if (!obj || !obj.customFieldValueName) return acc; // If it doesn't meet assertions just return the existing accumulator (don't add another element .ie 'null')
            return [                        
                ...acc,                      // If it conforms to the assertions the return a new accumulator, by first spreading in all existing elements and the adding the new one (customFieldValueName)
                customFieldValueName
            ]
        },[])                      // BIG-O notation: This is O(1N) or O(N), as in it will only iterate over the Array one time and the reduce() function will filter out 'null' values at the same time
      })
    }
})
```

**NOTE:** 
*I also just added `.filter(elem=> elem)` to the end of my first example, which does the same thing as the new `.reduce()` functionality, but does this in `1N` not `2N` operations.*

**PRE-logged data**

Here's how the `Array.map()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works...

```
[1,2].map(element=> {
// element === 1, first iteration,
// element === 2, second iteration
})
```

Here's how [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) works...

```
[one, two, ...theRest] = [1,2,3,4,5]

// one === 1 and two === 2 and theRest = [3,4,5]
```

Here's how [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) works...

```
{one, three, ...theRest} = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5}

// one === 1 and three === 3 and theRest === {two: 2, four: 4, five: 5}
// notice order doesn't matter here (three vs two), but you need to access valid properties from the object you're deetructuring from
```

So based on the way you function is structured you are making the assumption that the data structure of `response.data` is...

```
response.data === [ 
   [ 
     { customFieldValueName: 'any value' }, // label
     {}                                     // CustomStep (this could be any value, not necessarily an Object) 
   ],
   [ 
     { customFieldValueName: 'any value' }, // label
     'any value'                            // CustomStep
   ]
]
```

I hope this helps conceptually, but if you'd like a workable solution we will need...

1. Data structure of `response.data`. Can you provide result of `console.log( JSON.stringify( response.data, null, 5) )`
2. Specific values you are trying to assign to the new `this.state.playerRanks` Array.

PS: A good way to see Object destructuring in action with your current code is to change...

`.then( response => {`

To

`.then( ({data}) => {`

Comment: Hey can you add back your comments since it will help us to understand

Comment: Wow, not sure what happened here, don't think I deleted this many. May have been a moderator 'cleaning up'? I do remember the topics we discussed and will add some notes + resources to my answer later tonight

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should be certain that `response.data` is an array of arrays, because for each iteration of `response.data.map`, the function you are providing to the `map` must receive an array to be able to successfully pull the `label` and `CustomStep` values, due to  the syntax with which you are destructuring the function parameter.

Imagine `data` in the following example is the `response.data` and the `parseData` function is the function you are passing to the `map`:

```
let data = [
  [{ customFieldValueName: 'field name' }, { stepData: {} }],
  [{ customFieldValueName: 'another field name' }, { stepData: {} }]
];

let parseData = ([label, CustomStep]) => console.log(label.customFieldValueName);

parseData(data[0]); // prints out 'field name'
```

Otherwise, if `response.data` is an array of objects, which it seems like it is due to you successfully being able to run `response.data.map(d => d.customFieldValueName)`, you could update your map to this (if you simply want to pull the `customFieldValueName` value out of the object):

```
response.data.map(({ customFieldValueName }) => customFieldValueName)
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply,  I saw in console, data is an array inside that there are so many objects...updated output in my question